# django queryset filter foreignkey

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I'm having problems trying to use the queryset filter with my models.
It is a control for posts in groups.

This is my code:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()


class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)


class Control(models.Model):
    published = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm trying to get all posts from a group with the title "title":

```
queryset_list = Control.objects.filter(group__control="title")
```

My models might nit be right, I'm new to this.
Any help?

Comment: Why do you have the `Control` model? Is it possible for a `Post` to be published in one group and not in another?

Comment: Yes, I might have different Posts for specific Groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it typo error?

```
queryset_list = Control.objects.filter(group__title="title")
#                                             ^^^^^^
posts_title = queryset_list.values('post__title')
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should add a `ManyToManyField` on `Group` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)):

```
class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    posts = models.ManyToManyField('Post', through='Control')
```

The other two models remain the same, but now you can easily grab posts for a Group:

```
posts = Group.objects.get(title='some title').posts.all()
```

Comment: I got this error: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/renan/django/social-posts/src/control/models.py", line 21, in <module>
    class Control(models.Model):
  File "/home/renan/django/social-posts/src/control/models.py", line 24, in Control
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
NameError: name 'Group' is not defined

Comment: Assuming you moved Group below Control? Put `Group` in quotes: `group = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: Well, it didn't work either. This is my code (without the manytomany relation): https://bitbucket.org/renanbs/social-posts.

Comment: Same error or something else? Did you take a look at the docs I linked to in the answer? Hard to help without seeing the code + error.

Comment: This is the error: <locals>.resolve_through_model at 0x7ff5f28f81e0> contains a lazy reference to groups.control, but app 'groups' doesn't provide model 'control'.
groups.Group.posts: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Post', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
groups.Group.posts: (fields.E307) The field groups.Group.posts was declared with a lazy reference to 'groups.post', but app 'groups' doesn't provide model 'post'.
groups.Group.posts: (fields.E331) Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model 'Control', which has not been installed.

Comment: Looks like the models you posted are in separate `models.py`? If you're referring to different apps, you have to do something like `ForeignKey('app_name.Model')`. If your `Group` model is in `groups/models.py`, the field should be `groups = models.ForeignKey('groups.Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`. [The docs on ForeignKey go over this a bit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)