# django how to model this table correctly?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Following the suggestions from my last [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393989/django-queryset-filter-foreignkey) I got this far:

Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
```

Group model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    contact_updated = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    group_status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    admin = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    admin_status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    frequency = models.IntegerField()  # allowed post frequency
    frq_scale = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    obs = models.TextField(blank=True)

    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post, through='control.Control')
```

Control model:

```
class Control(models.Model):
    published = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    post = models.ForeignKey('posts.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey('groups.Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is control for posts in groups. I can have 1 post published in many groups controlled from Control model.

**CORRECTION**:
It is possible for a Post to be published in **many** groups.

How can I produce the table (link above) with those models? Or perhaps there is something I need to change?

[The table I want to produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWZ2Y.png)

Comment: You do not need the Control model. Just add the published attribute to Post model and you are good to go

Comment: I made a correction. A post can be published in several groups, that's why I need the Control model.

Comment: @RenanBiegelmeyer is the `published` field a date of a post or a date of a relation?

Comment: It's ok your models. You need "published" attribute in Control only if one post may be published in one group and not in other. Else, you can put "published" in Post and remove from Control

Comment: In the case a post is published in 2 groups, how can I get them using the Control class?

Comment: @AntonShurashov the published field is the date of a relation between the post and the group.

Comment: @RenanBiegelmeyer If a post has many groups, will it have one published date or different dates for each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a dictionary in the view to be passed to the template.
I haven't changed the models.

This is the view:

```
def control_list(request):
group_status = STATUS_LIST
group_query_idx = 1
period_initial = date.today()-timedelta(days=30)
period_final = date.today()

if request.method == "POST":
    filter_form = FilterControl(request.POST)
    if filter_form.is_valid():
        group_query_idx = int(filter_form.cleaned_data['group_status'])
        period_initial = filter_form.cleaned_data['period_initial']
        period_final = filter_form.cleaned_data['period_final']

else:
    filter_form = FilterControl()

if group_query_idx:
    filtered_groups = Group.objects.filter_by_status(group_status[group_query_idx])

queryset_list = Control.objects.filter_by_group_status(group_status[group_query_idx])\
    .filter(published__range=[period_initial, period_final])

query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
        Q(post__content__icontains=query) |
        Q(post__title__icontains=query) |
        Q(group__title__icontains=query) |
        Q(group__admin__icontains=query) |
        Q(group__obs__icontains=query)
    ).distinct()  # avoid duplicated items

controls_per_group = {}
for group in filtered_groups:
    control = queryset_list.filter(group_id=group.id)
    controls_per_group[group.title] = control

context = {
    "object_list": queryset,
    "title": "Control",
    "controls_per_group": controls_per_group,
    "column": range(10),
    "group_status": group_status,
    "filter_form": filter_form,
}
return render(request, "control_list.html", context)
```

And this is the template:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
<thead class="thead-inverse">
<tr>
    <th class="text-center">Action</th>
    <th class="text-center">Group</th>
    {% for value in column %}
    <th class="text-center">#</th>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
</thead>

{% for key, value in controls_per_group.items %}
    <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs disabled' href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs disabled"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
    <th class="text-center">{{ key }}</th>
    {% for control in value %}
        <th class="text-center"><a href="{{ control.post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ control.published | date:"d/m/y" }}<br>{{ control.post.id }}</a></th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Control(models.Model):
    published = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    post = models.ForeignKey('posts.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey('groups.Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (post, group )
```